# Cannot open file

Tags: c#, web-services, file

I am using this code to read a file using web services,

```
FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(FileName);
byte[] contents = new byte[stream.Length];
stream.Read(contents, 0, (int)stream.Length);
stream.Close();
```

but I get this error

> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to
>   process request. ---> Cannot open file "fileName.pdf". ---> Cannot
>   open file "filename.pdf".    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage
>   message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean
>   asyncCall)    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String
>   methodName, Object[] parameters)    at

Its random as well, sometimes it through error sometimes it doesn't.

Code is being used by 200+ users and it only throws exception randomly.

Comment: `filename.pdf` does not exist?  Or at least not in the directory that the service is looking in?  Try to include the _entire_ path to the file.

Comment: Does this exception have an inner exception?

Comment: @DStanley it happens randomly... and works next moment.

Comment: Did you tried `File.Exists(path)`?

Comment: @Renan Nope code is on production server, no other exceptions

Comment: is that filepath ever being opened with a lock anywhere else?

Comment: Are you changing the file at some point with code? How is the file fetched?

Comment: 2 people cannot open a file at same time, let alone 200.

Answer (score 0):

Excuse my ignorance of web services' HTTP implementation, it may account for this 
but if you are handling requests concurrently then two requests at the same time could potentially cause file contention.

You could potentially address this with a lock(obj){ } around the code or some more complex marshalling.

Answer (score 0):

Open the file using shared access using [this method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y973b725.aspx)

```
public static FileStream Open(
    string path,
    FileMode mode,
    FileAccess access,
    FileShare share
)
```

EDIT ADDED

Just to be sure, any place you can open this file, you need to open it shared. If anything outsize the web server can be opening the file (and you can't make it share read-only too). You can likely work-around the problem by trapping the exception when opening the file, sleep for 100 msec (or some other small amount) and retry up to nn time. This is not a good solution, just a hack to work-around the problem as your will tie up your server thread will you do this. But, if this hack works, you will know that this is the actual problem (file contention)